# yq - Run several filters in the row

Tags: yaml, yq

I've a YAML file representing the releases of a project:

```yaml
releases:
  - name: v0.1.0
    changes:
      added:
        - Second feature (#4)
      fixed:
        - Second fix (#5)
  - name: v0.0.1
    changes:
      fixed:
        - First fix (#3)
      security:
  - name: v0.0.1
    changes:
      added:
        - Bootstrap the project (#1)
        - First feature (#2)
```

I'm searching the correct recipe to get the following result:

```
v0.1.0
Second feature (#4)
Second fix (#5)
v0.0.1
First fix (#3)
v0.0.1
Bootstrap the project (#1)
First feature (#2)
```

For now, the closest I've gotten is:

```
v0.1.0
v0.0.1
v0.0.1
Second feature (#4)
Bootstrap the project (#1)
First feature (#2)
Second fix (#5)
First fix (#3)
```

With the following recipe:

```
.releases[] | (
  .name,
  .changes.added[],
  .changes.fixed[]
)
```

From what I understand, with my current recipe, all the items in `releases` will be provided to the filter `.name`, then all the items in `releases` will be provided to `.changes.added[]`, etc.

Is there a way to provide one item to the three filters, then another one, etc.?

Thanks in advance!

Edit (October 1st, 2023): I'm using [`mikefarah`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) flavor of `yq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected result is the default behavior with [jq](https://github.com/jqlang/jq), and thus also with [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq). With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), however, it's different, but you can induce this behavior by storing the iteration value in a variable:

```bash
.releases[] as $r | (
  $r.name,
  $r.changes.added[],
  $r.changes.fixed[]
)
```

```
v0.1.0
Second feature (#4)
Second fix (#5)
v0.0.1
First fix (#3)
v0.0.1
Bootstrap the project (#1)
First feature (#2)
```

Note: Depending on your actual use-case (especially wrt "interfering" values), you also might want to consider employing a [recursive descent](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/recursive-descent-glob) `..`, which traverses the tree in document order. Reduce this stream by using a reasonable discriminator, e.g. for this sample, it suffices filtering for strings to get your desired output:

```bash
.releases | .. | select(tag == "!!str")
```